# Analysis of motion of a body moving on a string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, rigid-body-dynamics, string

I was wondering about something I observed yesterday. To give some background, one of my hobbies is slacklining. This is essentially like tight-rope walking but with a one inch piece of (in this case polyester) webbing. Usually the set-up is you have an anchor around a tree, a pulley system, the webbing, then another anchor around a second tree. Thus a 'static' end and a non-static end. You tension the line to an appropriate amount and the goal is to walk from one end to the other, working on balance and what not.

Anyways, yesterday there was a little bit of wind and when I stood on top of the webbing, the line, that was initially just barely whipping in the wind, started to oscillate up and down, and as I continued to stand on the line, the amplitude seemed to build on itself and get to be larger and larger oscillations. Once I got off the line it came back to just being in the air.

My question is this, what is going on and what is the best way to model this motion? Is it some kind of driven oscillatory motion? I'm not bouncing up and down, just standing on top. Do the waves travel through the line, into the tree and back building on itself?

How accurate of an analysis is possible? What method should be used? Statics, Dynamics, Lagrangian? Any input would be very welcome.

Comment: Sounds like the position you were standing on it and the tension induced in the line changed its resonant frequency to match the driven oscillations caused by the wind. I imagine that had you moved to a different spot on the line, the oscillations would have abated a  bit. Very cool that you picked the right spot. Reminds me of the Tacoma Narrows bridge

Comment: @ACuriousJim It does seem very similar! I was standing on one end, essentially touching the tree. When you are walking closer to the middle taking steps cause the line to move, but not to the same degree if that makes sense.

Comment: it is possible you hit some kind of resonance by adjusting your knees slightly in sync with the natural frequency of the system. So most of the energy came from you and not the wind.